# Get Multiple Values from A JPanel in a UI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

The following code opens a UI with four fields in which a user can write some information. Some values may already appear in the fields from previous uses.

How can I get/save these values from when the user clicks "ok"?

**Values to get**:

1. url (*JTextField*)
2. username (*JTextField*)
3. password (*JPasswordField*)
4. statement (*JTextArea*)

I thought that the values would get saved within the *JPanel* object *panelForm* but they do not.

Do I need an ActionListener, if so why?

```
JPanel panelForm = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

         JTextField url1 = new JTextField("https:testing.com");
         JTextField username1 = new JTextField("theDude");
         JTextArea statement = new JTextArea("This statement can becomme very very very long :)");
         statement.setLineWrap(true);
         statement.setWrapStyleWord(true);
         // statement will be written in at least 3 rows
         // before a scroll bar will be integrated
         statement.setRows(3);
         JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(statement);

         Insets insets = new Insets(2,2,2,2);
         GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1,1,GridBagConstraints.WEST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                                                                    insets,0,0);

         panelForm.add(new JLabel("Enter url: "),constraints);
         // move to the next cell of the column (or to the next "row")
         constraints.gridy++;
         panelForm.add(new JLabel("Enter username: "),constraints);
         constraints.gridy++;
         panelForm.add(new JLabel("Enter password: "),constraints);
         constraints.gridy++;
         panelForm.add(new JLabel("Enter statement: "), constraints);

         // move to the next cell of the row (or to the next "column")
         constraints.gridx = 1;
         //go again to the first row
         constraints.gridy = 0;
         // Make the component wide enough to fill its display area horizontally, but do not change its height.
         constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
         panelForm.add(url1,constraints);
         constraints.gridy++;
         panelForm.add(username1,constraints);
         constraints.gridy++;
         // with the columns number you adjust the size
         // of all fields since I use "ridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL" everywhere
         panelForm.add(new JPasswordField(25),constraints);
         constraints.gridy++;
         panelForm.add(scrollPane,constraints);
         int option  = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,panelForm, "Fill all the fields",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

        } else {
            // if the user clicks on "Cancel" or "x" the code terminates
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `url1.getText()` ... and repeat for the other fields.  Not really sure what the question is

Comment: @MadProgrammer By using url1.getText you will get back the following value *https:testin.com* This value appears from the last use. Now if the user enters a new URL in the UI, how can I get the new value?

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh boy. You are right. I do not get through how the system knows that I changed the value and how it saves it under url1.

Comment: The "system" knows because that's how it works.  When you type something into the text field, the underlying model is updated.  You then access the value through the "reference" to the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of your JTextFields in List collection, like this

```
List<JTextField> list = new ArrayLists<JTextField>();

for (int i=0; i < maxFields; i++) { 
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    list.add( textField );
}
```

And after this, when ok button is clicked you just get them all

```
for( JTextField f : list ) { 
   System.out.println( f.getText() ) ;
}
```